# Ocultar elementos de página web en WebView - Android Studio - Java

Tags: java, android, webview

Buen día estimados.

Tengo una aplicación android que muestra por un webview una página. Pero la página web tiene muchos elementos que no quiero mostrar y es por eso que los oculto de la siguiente manera:

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
               view.loadUrl ("javascript:(function() { "+"document.getElementsByClassName('td-header-wrap td-header-style-1 ')[0].style.display='none'; "+ "document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index ')[1].style.display='none';  "+"document.getElementsById('td_uid_1_5ff8cc46439eb ')[0].style.display='none'; "+"document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index ')[0].style.display='none';  "+"document.getElementsByClassName('tdm-mobile-full')[0].style.display='none'; "+"document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index ')[0].style.display='none'; "+"} )()");

  }
```

¿Es posible mediante una **función de javascript indicar solo lo que debe mostrarse** y no indicar lo que hay que ocultar?